# pre-certification, cobalt can't render webp page

Tags: youtube, cobalt

For YouTube pre-certification, cobalt needs to render some pages that YouTube assigned.
We test the three commands below:

```
./cobalt --url=http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp --allow_http --csp_mode=disable
./cobalt --url=http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp --disable_navigation_whitelist
./cobalt --url=http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp --disable_navigation_whitelist --allow_http
```

but cobalt renders nothing. Could someone guide us on how to render a webp page for pre-certification?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp is not Cobalt compatible.

Please use the following WebP test cases for the pre-certification.
https://qual-e.appspot.com/webp.html
https://qual-e.appspot.com/awebp.html

These sites might not work with Gold build as of now. I will make changes to these sites to work on Gold build and notify here once it's done.

Going forward, I will mention this in the pre-certification document.

Comment: Scrolling issue on awebp.html is a known issue.

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks. how about http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp? need to pass?

Comment: Use Qual-E webp.html and awebp.html

Comment: we see another issue that focused GIF item will render nothing. white picture only. is it correct?

Comment: It is expected that Cobalt does not support GIF. You can safely ignore it. GIF was used to help how the animation looks like.